# Correct antenna position ESP32 on custom board

Tags: pcb-design, esp32, pcb-antenna

Is the antenna position correct in this design? In the ESP32 hardware design document, they say:
[image]

The board hasn't copper or tracks under the antenna. I can't put the antenna on the edge because I need a few millimeters to put the enclosure. I cut the other side of the antenna from the board. What can happen for not following the recommended mounting steps of ESP32? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, this cutout is better than not having one, but there doesn't seem to be a reason why you didn't cut the whole thing through to the edge, which would be both easier to manufacture and better for RF.

The whole pink area could be trivially cut out:

[image: cutout]

Also, there seems to be no reason U3 sits that "high". You could easily move it down by 7mm and keep traces further away from the antenna.

> What can happen for not following the recommended mounting steps of ESP32?

You're de-tuning the antenna. That leads to worse reception, less transmit power, and in the end that means worse performance. Also, you're changing the radiation pattern in pretty much unforeseeable ways.

---

Also, I'm almost certain C4-C8 should not be all in one place, but as close as possible to the things that they are decoupling caps to. This is probably functionally much more relevant than your antenna placement. Your ground traces also don't look good – the current return paths seem pretty convoluted.

I'd say I'd re-place U3, Q1 and all the capacitors, then make sure a I have the current return ground paths directly under the supply lines (and signal lines, too), and then your layout will be much cleaner, and more importantly, you will have less noise and better supply stability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't cutout whole area because the design will be boxed in a enclosure that have these flanges https://i.imgur.com/WsFRC3B.png . I moved the components as you said, is it better now for the interferences?https://i.imgur.com/9YIPCRj.png

Comment: The capacitors are still completely in the wrong places.

Comment: Why? What is the correct position?